# Как преобразовать один Map в другой?

Tags: java, map, java-stream

Есть `Map<Entity,List<Integer>`, также имеется `Mapper` для `entity->dto` и обратно. Как из первой `Map` получить `Map<Dto,List<Integer>>` при помощи лямбд?

Comment: Покажите как Mapper работает. И обязательно лямбдами?

Comment: Mapper может , DTO Mapper.todto(Entity entity);Entity Mapper.toEntity(DTO dto);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<Entity, List<Integer>> srcMap = ...
Map<Dto, List<Integer>> dstMap = srcMap
                                   .entrySet()
                                   .stream()
                                   .collect(
                                     Collectors.toMap(
                                       e -> Mapper.toDto(e.getKey()),
                                       e -> e.getValue()));
```

Но на мой взгляд, использование лямбд здесь необоснованно и только приводит к дополнительному расходу ресурсов, хоть и небольшому. Проще воспользоваться циклом.